# iOS 9.2 - unable to see defaults registered from Settings.bundle in device Settings app

Tags: objective-c, ios9, plist, nsuserdefaults

I have a project which uses Settings.bundle including root.plist containing a list of key value pairs I want to register with user defaults. Until recently, these values were visible and editable from the device's "Settings" App. Now I can't see anything when tapping on my app in settings - the details panel is empty.

**How can I make sure my key-value pairs from the Settings.bundle provided with app properly display in the device's settings app?**

Edit: It seems that restarting the settings app fixes the issue, but the details pane goes blank again if I redeploy the app from Xcode. Is it something with the new version of iOS that I'm not aware of?

Here's my code to register defaults:

```
- (void)registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle {
    NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
    if(!settingsBundle) {
        DLog(@"Could not find Settings.bundle");
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"]];
    NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

    NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];
    for(NSDictionary *prefSpecification in preferences) {

        NSString *key = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"Key"];

        if(key && [[prefSpecification allKeys] containsObject:@"DefaultValue"]) {

            id object = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
            if(object != nil)
            {
                [defaultsToRegister setObject:object forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apple bug in iOS 9.2 and Simulator 9.2

Comment: I've seen the same- seems like the first time I run and go to settings everything is fine, and on subsequent times everything is gone!